# Laravel flash message not working

Tags: php, laravel

As of now I have no idea why my flash message isn't working. The idea is, to display a "danger" sort of message that the login has failed due the account not being activated. This is the code

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function login(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    // This section is the only change
    if ($this->guard()->validate($this->credentials($request))) {
        $user = $this->guard()->getLastAttempted();

        // Make sure the user is active
        if ($user->verified_at !== null && $this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            // Send the normal successful login response
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        } else {
            // Increment the failed login attempts and redirect back to the
            // login form with an error message.
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
            return redirect('/login')->with('Danger', 'You still haven|t activated your account ');

        }
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    if ($provider == null || ($user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user()) == null) {
        die('Not existing provider or user.');
    }

    return AuthProvider::findOrCreate($user, $provider);
}

public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
{
    $authUser = User::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();
    if ($authUser) {
        return $authUser;
    }
    return User::create([
        'name' => $user->name,
        'email' => $user->email,
        'provider' => $provider,
        'provider_id' => $user->id
    ]);
}
```

}

And I simply don't know why it isn't working. Any thoughts on how to resolve this? I've tried everything but yet again the results aren't what I expected them to be sadly. Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you put a html to display the error if there is an error?

Comment: Share your html where you want to display message ?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this but where did you learn how to implement the login by youserlf? I always used make:auth and controllers look empty af